# Permit IP Directed Broadcast on DELL FTOS

Tags: broadcast, dell, access-control, force10, wake-on-lan

OK so in cisco land you can add an acl to the ip directed broadcas command, but this option does not appear in FTOS (Dell Networking OS 9)

if you enable ip directed broadcast on the vlan and then apply an ACL which allows only allowed hosts to talk to the broadcast address and then permits any other traffic would this achieve the same effect?

E.g. the following config

```
conf t
ip access-list extended db10
permit udp host (WOLHostIP) any (BroadcastAddress) 0
permit udp host (WOLHost2IP) any (BroadcastAddress) 0
deny udp any (BroadcastAddress) 0
exit
int vlan 10
ip directed-broadcast
ip access-group db10 out implicit-permit
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, directed broadcasts are filtered on ingress for all interfaces. You need to enable directed-broadcast forwarding on the *incoming* interface.

In the interface config context you need to

```
 ip directed-broadcast
```

An ACE is only required with an active ACL on the interface not allowing this otherwise. Filtering to specific source addresses/patterns should work.